# Running virtual linux using qemu on windows

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

I am trying to use Qemu 1.3 for windows to run lubuntu on a USB stick with Windows 7. After downloading and unpacking Qemu on my usb stick, if I click on qemu.io.exe, I get

```
qemu-io.exe>
```

How do I start my downloaded linux .iso file? It sounds basic but its not clear to me from the Qemu website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Qemu manual](http://wiki.qemu.org/Manual) would be a  good place to start. It'll help you work out what you're supposed to do next, which is to tell qemu what to do, and exactly how to do that.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer, although the manual doesn't seem to be very specific for what I am trying to do. I'm not blown away by the docs here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: There's nothing worse than SO answers that just point you to the docs. Like, why else do you think we came here in the first place? Most Unix / systems-y tools have the worst documentation imaginable.

Comment: People commenting complaints in reply to answers from 9 years ago is worse, I'd say.

Answer (score 37):

Here is how I run a minimal version of CentOS 7 on a Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bits, without being a member of the administrator group (non-admin).

The basic idea is:

1. Download qemu for windows and unzip it anywhere
2. Download an ISO image of the Linux distribution you want to run
3. Create a file that will be your virtual machine hard disk
4. Run qemu, booting from the CD image
5. Install the OS
6. Reboot the virtual machine, this time without the CD image

Networking and fancy graphics are hard to get right. Still struggling, actually...

**1. Download QEMU**

Use a [precompiled binary found on QEMU links page](http://wiki.qemu.org/Links). I used [version 2.8.0 for this](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/).

To "install" this version as a non-admin, open a command prompt, issue the command `set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker` and run `qemu-w64-setup-20170131.exe` from that prompt. Install in a folder where you have write permissions, like "My Documents" or something.

**2. Download an ISO image of Linux**

Again, help yourself. I used the [Minimal distribution of CentOS 7](https://www.centos.org/download/), the file is called `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso`.

**3. Create a virtual hard disk**

I used a batch file for this. Copy the following to a file named `createvm.bat` and adjust the variables to suit your environment:

```bat
@echo off
rem ==================================
rem Replace with your values
rem ==================================
set "QEMUDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Warez\qemu-2.8.0-win64"

rem ==================================
rem Safety net
rem ==================================
if not exist hda.img (
    rem CREATE a virtual hard disk 
    "%QEMUDIR%\qemu-img.exe" create hda.img 40G
) else (
    echo file hda.img already exist. Delete or move and try again.
    goto:eof
)
```

**4. Run QEMU, booting from the virtual CD**

Use a batch for this one, as you might use it often. Copy the follwing into `installvm.bat`:

```bat
@echo off

rem ==================================
rem Replace with your values
rem ==================================
set "QEMUDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Warez\qemu-2.8.0-win64"
set "ISOFILE=CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso"

rem ==================================
rem You can add a w suffix to this if 
rem you don't want a console
rem ==================================
set "QEMUBIN=qemu-system-x86_64.exe"

rem ==================================
rem Run the virtual machine
rem ==================================
start "QEMU" "%QEMUDIR%\%QEMUBIN%" -drive file=hda.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom %ISOFILE% -m 2G -L Bios -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -boot menu=on -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -parallel none -serial none -name centos -no-acpi -no-hpet -no-reboot
```

**5. Install the OS**

I had trouble with the GUI installer. When prompted to install CentOS, hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and replace the word `quiet` at the end of that line with the word `text`.

Follow the installation instructions on screen. When the installation is finished, the virtual machine will exit. It can take quite a while, especially when running as a non-admin user.

**6. Run your Linux image in QEMU**

This step is what you will do over and over again to run the VM each time you need it. Copy the follwing into `runvm.bat`:

```bat
@echo off

rem ==================================
rem Replace with your values
rem ==================================
set "QEMUDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Warez\qemu-2.8.0-win64"

rem ==================================
rem You can add a w suffix to this if 
rem you don't want a console
rem ==================================
set "QEMUBIN=qemu-system-x86_64.exe"

rem ==================================
rem Run the virtual machine
rem ==================================
start "QEMU" "%QEMUDIR%\%QEMUBIN%" -drive file=hda.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -m 2G -L Bios -usbdevice mouse -usbdevice keyboard -boot menu=on -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -parallel none -serial none -name centos -no-acpi -no-hpet -no-reboot -device e1000,netdev=user.0 -netdev user,id=user.0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

I added a local portforward : if you ssh/putty to localhost:2222, you will reach the SSH daemon of your VM. Beware that `firewalld` or `iptables` *might* block traffic, depending on the way you installed Linux.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: can this be managed with qtemu ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Managed with qemu"... I suggest you **ask a new question** (and maybe link to this one).